# Prototype Alternative in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can i replace prototype and make the same code below to work? in other words i wanna write a code with the same meaning/logic without using prototype.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + 
        this.substr(index + character.length);              
}
```

Comment: You can simply define it as a function/method of an object.

Comment: Mr.Ahmed i tried to implement your method, but it's not working for some reason. is it possible to make a separate function that can do the same job. my only problem is, i cant show all my project publicly. is it possible to communicate with u privately?

Comment: Can you show me how you are defining and using it? There might be something wrong there......

Comment: am using it for a spellchecker program.  in-line function to replace character in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Create it as a method of a custom utility object -

```
var StringUtils = {};

StringUtils.replaceAt = function (str, index, character) {
    return str.substr(0, index) + character + 
        str.substr(index + character.length);
}
```

and then call it like this -

```
var str = "Hello";
StringUtils.replaceAt(str, 0, "A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just define it as a function and use the call or apply prototype method

```
replaceAt = function(index, character) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
```

**How to use?**

```
var str = "Javascript is Awesome";
replaceAt.call(str, 0, "A");
// or 
replaceAt.apply(str, [0, "A"]);
```

Comment: You see, it's not a good idea to force the use of `apply`/`call` by using `this` inside the function. It's not intuitive and hence can create hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @SayemAhmed True, I was not sure how extreme the questioner was about "same meaning/logic". Your method is how I would probably do it.